# add a tooltip to 2graph vis.js library

Tags: vis.js

I am using a 2d line graph of vis.js (http://visjs.org/graph2d_examples.html ). Is there any way to add a tooltip to the data points so that when you mouse over or click you see the value in a pop up or somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a feature they plan on adding.. the closest thing I see is this comment on trying to tackle the issue themselves:

https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/282#issuecomment-65728474

Answer (score -1):

This solution is rather simpe:

Add label to points, eg.

```
var point = {
    x: ...,
    y: ...,
    label: {
        content: POINT_LABEL
    }
};

points.push(point);

var dataset = new vis.DataSet(points);
```

Reference:
https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/282#issuecomment-217528166